# Password is matched ok with regular expression, but cannot proceed to next form

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc, razor

I will be really thankful and appreciate it if anyone tries to help me to solve this problem.

I have a metadata class with data annotations for validation in Registration Forms. One of some fields in the Registration Forms is Password. I use a **regular expression** for password validation, and this is the code:

```
[Display(Name = "Password")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Password required")]
[RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$", ErrorMessage = "Combination of Uppercase, Lowercase and Numeric are required")]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[MinLength(8, ErrorMessage = "Minimum 8 characters required")]
public string password { get; set; }
```

The *ErrorMessage* will appear when the password string is not matched with the *RegularExpression* that requires at least 8 characters with at least 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, and 1 numeric. Passwords not matched with the regular expression are like:

- christo (less than 8 character)
- christopher (no uppercase & numeric)
- Christopher (no numeric)
- etc

When passwords like the above sample was entered, then the error message *"Combination of Uppercase, Lowercase and Numeric are required"* will appear. And that is working so far.

But here is the problem. When I enter a password like

- Christopher123 or
- Julius97

and click the submit button, the registration does not proceed to the next page, even though the error message doesn't appear.

I really hope anyone can help me. Thanks a lot.

This is the screenshot after i put Christopher123 as a password and i click Create button. There is no error message but my project doesn't proceed to the next page.

[Registration Forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvTqW.png)

Comment: do you see any message in the debug or output windows inside VS

Comment: Obviously you regex is wrong. The error message does not mean your password is not valid by your rules - it means that the password is not valid BY THE REGEX. Use a regex test site (tons of them, use google) to find the error in your regex.

Comment: when you enter the Christophes123 password put a breakpoint inside the controller method call and verify all the errors  with this code: `IEnumerable<ModelError> allErrors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors)` is it showing what is wrong?

Comment: I do agree with @TomTom, also if you'll be using MinLength. I think its better to not include the `{8,}` part in your regex. So that your MinLength validation will catch it. yes, the regex is wrong. try to validate your regex first. it accepts strings like christopher123.
But then again, you still need to debug it. try to check your ModelState.IsValid if it's true, then the error is not in your validation.

Comment: Why do you think your problem is related to the regex match? No one here can help you find the reason with the current information you gave. Unless you add debugging details to your topic it's unsalvageable.

Comment: @Saravanan no, i didn't see any messages in the debug or output windows inside VS

Comment: @TomTom i try to use that regex for username validation `[DataType(DataType.Text)]` and it's work. String like Christopher123 is accepted

Comment: @Josh i have deleted `{8,}' part in my regex, but still doesn't work

Comment: in your saving method, do you have something like `if(ModelState.IsValid) { // code of saving}` ?